# buildConfigField does not recover my api key from gradle.properties

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to secure my API key because I want to upload a public repository, I tried with this at my gradle and added the keys to the `gradle.properties` file

### build.gradle

```
 buildTypes {

        debug {
            buildConfigField 'String', "FIRST_APIKEY", "\"FIRST_APIKEY\""
            buildConfigField 'String', "SECOND_APIKEY", "\"SECOND_APIKEY\""
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

### gradle.properties

```
FIRST_APIKEY = "apikey"
SECOND_APIKEY = "apikey"
```

where it says apikey is the current alphanumeric apikey

and when I implement this into a class to get that apikey it does not return the apikey

For example here Im trying to parse data from that apikey but I dont get nothing because it cant be reached

```
service.getData(BuildConfig.FIRST_APIKEY)....
```

The result of BuildConfig.FIRST_APIKEY with the debugger is the followin

> result = FIRST_APIKEY

instead of FIRST_APIKEY it should implement my apikey that I previously configurated in the `gradle.properties` file

Thanks for any tip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, load your properties to `Properties` object in configuration phase of gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

Properties localProperties = new Properties()
localProperties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
```

And then you can find your property for `buildConfigField`:

```
buildConfigField 'String', "FIRST_APIKEY", localProperties.getProperty('FIRST_APIKEY')
buildConfigField 'String', "SECOND_APIKEY", localProperties.getProperty('SECOND_APIKEY')
```

If your properties looks like these:

```
FIRST_APIKEY=apikey
SECOND_APIKEY=apikey
```

Then you need to replace `localProperties.getProperty('FIRST_APIKEY')` to `"\"${props.getProperty('FIRST_APIKEY')}\""`.

Answer (score 1):

you should not assign a static string, but rather a variable:

```
buildConfigField("String", "FIRST_APIKEY", "\"${firstApiKey}\"")
resValue("string", "first_api_key", "${firstApiKey}")
```

and it might not care about any `.properties`, unless loading them; for example:

```
def apikeys = new Properties()
apikeys.load(new FileInputStream(rootProject.file('apikeys.properties')))
project.ext.set('firstApiKey', apikeys['firstApiKey'])
```